# Cannot deploy compiled scala play application with sub projects to Heroku

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework-2.0

I have a play project, composed of sub projects, that I use on Heroku. I am using Play 2.3 with Scala 2.11.4

**Goal**

- I want to take away most if not all of the compilation out of the
  deploy cycle. I have two main drivers:  I feel that for production
  code I want to be deploying jars and not source code
- Compilation on
  Heroku takes about ten times longer than compilation on my machine

**Approach**

My approach has been to 'publish' the project jars to Maven and then ship a project that just uses the published artifacts. This works on my machine, but when I deploy it to Heroku it fails to compile: it cannot find the 'controllers.ReverseXXX'.

My actual application is now thousands of files, but I have managed to recreate the problem with a much smaller project available on github. I am deploying to a local self contained maven repository to ease duplication of this problem. The two projects required to recreate the issue are  https://github.com/stave-escura/mainChildPlayApp and https://github.com/stave-escura/deploy

Steps to reproduce the problem

```
git clone https://github.com/stave-escura/mainChildPlayApp.git
cd mainChildPlayApp
git clone https://github.com/stave-escura/deploy.git
sbt
>publish
>run
    {At this point if you go to localhost:9000 you should see Main Hello world and localhost:9000/child should produce Child Hello World}
    {terminate the run with Ctrl-d}
exit
cd deploy
sbt
>run
    {At this point if you go to localhost:9000 you should see Main Hello world and localhost:9000/child should produce Child Hello World}
    {terminate the run with Ctrl-d}
>exit

heroku git:remote -a  <put in here the git repository details for your heroku app>
git add --all :/
git commit -m "Initial Commit"
git push --force heroku master
```

Even though the project worked locally (checked by the runs) it fails on Heroku with messages like

```
   [error] /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main/controllers/routes.java:16: error: package controllers.ref does not exist
   [error] public static final controllers.ref.ReverseApplication Application = new controllers.ref.ReverseApplication();
```

**Summary of what is going on:**

My project directory is

```
Project
   app
      ...
   conf
      ...
   public
      ...
   deploy
   modules
      child
         conf
         public
      main
         conf
         public
```

During the publish I have made an SBT plugin to copy the conf and public directories to deploy (merging them), and I publish the maven artifacts to a sub directory under deploy as well. Thus the deploy structure after the publish becomes

```
Project
  ...
  Deploy
    Conf
    Public
    Maven
```

My sbt in the deploy directory looks like this

```
organization := "org.myorg"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.11.4"

resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

resolvers += "Local" at new File("maven").toURI.toURL+"snapshots"

libraryDependencies +=    "org.myorg" %% "proj" % "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val deployedWebsite = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

It is the git repository in the deploy directory that is sent to Heroku.

**Disclaimer**

I've managed to duplicate the error on my machine following these instructions. If they don't work for you (either instructions are wrong, or you get a different result) please let me know. It's complicated reporting issues like this!

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for this is the [sbt-heroku plugin](https://github.com/heroku/sbt-heroku). It is support by Heroku. It does not handle sub projects well yet, but there is [and open issue for sub project](https://github.com/heroku/sbt-heroku/issues/4) that will hopefully be fixed soon.

Comment: That issue is fixed now, and subprojects are handle well by sbt-heroku.

Comment: When using the sbt-heroku plugin, keep in mind you'll need to upload your compiled resources every time you deploy. Depending on your upload speed and the size of your app this may take some time.